# Import "django.(any module)" could not be resolved from sourcePylancereportMissingModuleSource, missing python file

Tags: python, django

I found similar questions but all the answers pointed to the wrong interpreter. However, when I go to the Scripts folder, there is no "python.exe". I have the latest python version installed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUaMF.png)

Comment: can you run "pip freeze" in the command terminal and post the results?

Comment: Sure!  asgiref==3.5.2
autopep8==1.6.0
certifi==2022.6.15
charset-normalizer==2.1.0
-e git+https://github.com/django/django.git@8c3046daade8d9b019928f96e53629b03060fe73#egg=Django
idna==3.3
peppercorn==0.6
pycodestyle==2.8.0
pyperclip==1.8.2
requests==2.28.1
sampleproject @ git+https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject.git@918bd331501de42be32666bd5140d04d00b39386
sqlparse==0.4.2
toml==0.10.2
tzdata==2022.1
urllib3==1.26.11

Comment: OK I'm seeing why there are problems with not finding django modules. Did you make a virtual environment? you don't necessarily need to, but it matters whether you did or not in this case

Comment: I did not make one.

Comment: from this pip freeze result, it looks like django isn't installed where it should be, can you run "python -m pip install Django" and let me know if it says "successfully installed"

Comment: It says "Requirement already satisfied:"

Requirement already satisfied: Django in c:\users\krysm\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (4.2.dev20220811103954)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in c:\users\krysm\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from Django) (0.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: tzdata in c:\users\krysm\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from Django) (2022.1)
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref>=3.5.2 in

Comment: I think it has installed 4.2 (development edition), this is very new (and I believe it's still under development). I think only very few python versions are working with this right now. To overcome this import problem, run from the terminal: "python -m pip install Django==4.1". I'm using this version and it is the proper one to use right now.

Comment: If you run "pip freeze" again you should be able to find "Django==4.1"

Comment: OMG, it worked may God bless you, kind stranger! I don't have any rewards, but you deserve one. I can't wait to start learning django. 
Have a fantastic day!

Comment: No problem, good to get it working! Django shouldn't have installed 4.2 package, I don't know why it installed this one automatically.